# I cannot create the .click() action on the button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I cannot create the `.click()`-action on the button.

HTML:

```
<button class="btn__type btn__type_close">Закрыть</button>
```

I try to make an element clickable for execute_script:

```
driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByClassName('.btn__type_close')").click()
```

My code using Selenium:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.btn__type_close').click()
```

None of the methods is working.

---

Question: How will it be correct?

Comment: What if will you do the same actions in browser's console? Is it working or not?

Comment: What does *"None of the methods did not work"* means? Did you get any exception?

Comment: Did you try my updated answer?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try clicking using XPath?

```
WebElement btnClose=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn__type btn__type_close']"));
            if(btnClose.isEnabled()){
                btnClose.click();
            }
```